# Does a difference of variables generate the same Sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

When reading the textbook *Probability and Measure*, I found the below part,

> Note that, since $X_k=\Delta_1+\cdots+\Delta_k$ and $\Delta_k=X_k-X_{k-1}$, the sets $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ and $\Delta_1,\ldots, \Delta_n$ generate the same $\sigma$-field:
>   \begin{align}(35.8)&\qquad&\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)=\sigma(\Delta_1,\ldots, \Delta_n)&\qquad&&&&\end{align}

Whatever I try to do, I cannot approach to $(35.8)$.

Can anyone prove this?

Comment: I am sure the case $n=3$ suffices to make you understand the general case. For one inclusion, note that $(\Delta_1,\Delta_2,\Delta_3)=G(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ with $$G(x,y,z)=(x,y-x,z-y).$$ For the other inclusion, note that $(X_1,X_2,X_3)=H(\Delta_1,\Delta_2,\Delta_3)$ with $$H(u,v,w)=(u,u+v,u+v+w).$$

Comment: @Did Thanks. The above claim is possible, since the elements are not constants but measurable functions(random variable). Am I right?

Comment: Not related to the question. Why do you bring this element to the fore?

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma(X_1,\cdots, X_n)=\mathcal E$ is the *smallest* $\sigma$-field such that each $X_i$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable. $\mathcal E$-measurable functions $\Omega\to\Bbb R$ are an algebra (in the algebraic sense), therefore each $\Delta_i$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable.

Let $\mathcal F=\sigma(\Delta_1,\cdots,\Delta_n)$. We showed that $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal E$. For the same reason $\mathcal E\subseteq \mathcal F$.

Comment: Thank you for your correcting my question in detail ,and answer. However, while trying to do by myself using some real numbers(say, 1, 2 and 3) put in $X_{n}$, I could not justify this. If you don't mind, could you repeat this by some example?

Comment: @kurtkim I don't believe specific examples are useful to clarify the thing I said. It's really an application of the general fact that, given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal E$ and two $\mathcal E$-measurable functions $f,g:\Omega\to\Bbb R$, then $f+g$ and $f-g$ are $\mathcal E$-measurable, paired with the fact that, if $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ are $\mathcal E$-measurable, then $\sigma(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\subseteq \mathcal E$. User Did's comment suggests a *different* approach from mine, which basically relies on Doob-Dynkin lemma.

Comment: I got it. First, I only took account of some fixed sets(say, $A_{i}$) for $X_{i}$ and $\Delta_{i}$, which does not make any sense. But these are random variables(functions).